# How to parse JSON results in to a dynamic object

Tags: c#, json, parsing, mailchimp, restsharp

I'm trying to write a C# utility to consume the results returned from the [Export API by MailChimp](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/export/1.0/).

The documentation states that the results will be returned as "streamed JSON."

> "This means that a call to this API will not return a single valid JSON
>   object but, rather, a series of valid JSON objects separated by
>   newline characters."

The results that I'm seeing don't look like normal JSON to me, and aren't what I was expecting to be working with. It looks to me like CSV data wrapped in square brackets, with row headers in the first line.

A snip of the results [can be viewed here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Richard-West/10756239/raw/0bcaa6dbd82c9cf25405514dd68c514fa5d1a547/gistfile1.txt). I'll paste them below as well.

```
["Email Address","First Name","Last Name","Company","FirstOrder","LastOrder","CustomerID","SalesRep","ScreenName","PlayerPage","PlayerPDF","Services Purchased","Contests","EMAIL_TYPE","MEMBER_RATING","OPTIN_TIME","OPTIN_IP","CONFIRM_TIME","CONFIRM_IP","LATITUDE","LONGITUDE","GMTOFF","DSTOFF","TIMEZONE","CC","REGION","LAST_CHANGED","LEID","EUID"]
["john@domain.com","John","Doe","ACME Inc","2010-09-07","2010-09-07","ABC123","sally","","","","Service1","","html",2,"",null,"2011-12-23 15:58:44","10.0.1.1","34.0257000","-84.1418000","-5","-4","America\/Kentucky\/Monticello","US","GA","2014-04-11 18:38:39","40830325","82c81e14a"]
["jane@domain2.com","Jane","Doe","XYZ Inc","2011-05-02","2011-05-02","XYZ001","jack","","","","Service2","","html",2,"",null,"2011-12-23 15:58:44","10.0.1.1","34.0257000","-84.1418000","-5","-4","America\/Kentucky\/Monticello","US","GA","2014-04-11 18:38:40","40205835","6c23329a"]
```

Can you help me understand what is being returned -- as it doesn't appear to be normal JSON. And what would be my best approach to parse this stream of data into a C# object.

EDIT: I've confirmed that the data stream is valid JSON using http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html and pasting in the sample lines above. So what I'm hoping for is a way to dynamically create an object based on the first line, then create a list of these objects with the values contained in the subsequent lines.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, this is not in typical JSON form.  What you could do is create a collection of `Dictionary<string, string>` objects.  Use the first part of the response to use as the keys of the dictionaries and then the values found in subsequent pieces of the result as the values of each dictionary.

Comment: I've confirmed that this valid JSON -- at least it validates when I paste in a few lines at http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html

Comment: So I'm still hoping for a solution that would allow me to dynamically create and object based on the headers, in the first line, and read the additional lines as values.

Comment: @RichardWest I think jensendp meant that although it's "valid" JSON, it's not "normal". Usually, each object is self contained rather than getting a "header" JSON object that describes the details.

Comment: You are correct, and I did not mean to imply otherwise. It is just not "typical" JSON :-)

Comment: Thank you mason, that is what I was trying to convey.  :)  @RichardWest Unless you know the fields that you will be getting ahead of time, it will be difficult to create a predefined type.  You could of course use a "dynamic" object in C#, but once again in order to retrieve the values, you would either need to know them explicitly, or you would have to transform the dynamic object into a Dictionary to get the values through a loop of some sort.  I feel like this just adds another layer of complexity, though you may go that route if you wish.  That is why I suggested just using a Dictionary.